# Why can't I zoom to Google Charts lat, long markers at state level, instead of whole US?

Tags: maps, zooming, google-maps-markers, google-visualization, markers

I'm trying to zoom in on the markers slightly (current map view: entire US) but I'm struggling. I can't find a clear answer, following the documentation - many examples for a different style with .roadmap, not with this style. How would I do this?

```
function drawMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', 'Popularity'],
    <% citys.each do |key, value| %> 
    ["<%= key %>", <%= value %>], 
    <% end %>
    ["San Diego", 300]
  ]);

  var options = {};
  options['region'] = 'US';
  options['colors'] = [0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]; //orange colors
  options['dataMode'] = 'markers';

  var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
  geomap.draw(data, options);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The GeoMaps/GeoCharts are part of the Google Visualization API, not Google Maps, and they don't support zooming.  You can use the Maps API directly or you can use the [Maps wrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map) for the Visualization API to get zoom capabilities.

Comment: Glad to see you on Stack Overflow! You are the cream of the crop when it comes to the Google Visualization API -- can't wait to see what else we can learn from you!

Comment: Shame `Map` when used with Charts just gives pins, not a marker that actually denotes information of the measurement (value) being plotted on the map.